# Python request.get() returns 404 page not found

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, html

I have been having a little big of a funny behavior and would love an explanation as to why it is happening.

I am using the following to grab a page and then parse through it:

```
r  = requests.get(html)
```

Now when I run this on a windows computer with python on a Webpage A it gets back the page as you would expect.

However, when I run this same command on my Synology Diskstation(I believe Linux Based) it returns back a 404 page not found page instead of the entered url page.

When I try different URL's it gives me back the right page on both systems.

Any explanation as to how or why this is happening?

EDIT: Just tried it on my MacBook at home as well and it works just fine. But for some reason it still does not work on the Diskstation :S

EDIT:

Headers from two machines

Mac (Where it is working):

```
{'Content-Length': '17924', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=q86c56e1e4t1d8jsu0penc488oraladt; path=/', 'Vary': 'Host,Accept-Encoding', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=10, max=100', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 24 Jan 2017 04:31:08 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Diskstation (Where it is not):

```
{'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Vary': 'Host', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=10, max=100', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 24 Jan 2017 04:30:25 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Comment: What is the actual URL you're trying to fetch?

Comment: Are the Python versions the same on both platforms?

Comment: @Hromgo Yup! Just doubled checked and both are 2.7.12

Comment: @jwodder I would rather not mention it but I did find another website on which this happens on:  http://store.concept1.ca/Trunk-Liner-SB-Lower-71-79-133863505B-WW/

Comment: Look at both requests and see if the headers differ.

Comment: Can you get the file using wget or curl from Diskstation? One thought is your diskstation's IP may be blocked (some sites do that automatically if you hit them too often / frequently). Also, are any URLs using https? (Maybe your diskstation's certificate authority store differs.)

Comment: I was using a VPN and upon reading your comment thought it might be that but upon turning it off, it still results in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, either you are hitting a robots.txt issue or the header info sent is different between the 2 systems. A basic trace should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Could you provide more info? How would I go about doing a trace?   I am very new to both python and webscraping so I'm still learning a lot.

Comment: requests ignores robots.txt (robots.txt is 100% voluntary), but yes, check the headers sent and received: response headers are easy: `r.headers`. You might also check redirects. This info will be stored in `r.history`. Perhaps there's a bad redirect going on.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I did as you mentioned and it looks like r.history gives me [<Response [302]>] (Which is a redirect if I am not mistaken?  I have updated the original with the headers from the two different machines. Very much appreciate the help

Comment: Right, 302 is a redirect. Do Mac and Diskstation both show redirect (the same redirect?). The user-agent being sent by your diskstation, perhaps, is causing the server to redirect you to a bad location (maybe?). You might set your user-agent string (in you request) to match what is being sent by your mac.

Comment: @Peter No the redirect only shows up on the Diskstation. I will try setting the useragent and give it a try